# Diceroll game calculating points for a straight in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Javascript and my current task is to develop a simple dice game which allows the user to roll between 3 to 6 dice. Where N=number of dice.
When the dice is rolled points are gained for specific types of rolls, e.g if all dice are the same then the player gains 60 points(4,4,4,4), if all dice are the same apart from one (N-1)then 40points e.g 6,6,6,1.
Im unsure on how to code this next type of condition which is for 10 points towards the players score.It asks to calculate a straight. So if N=4 then 4 dice are rolled and if the dice values are for example (1,2,3,4),(4,3,2,1),(2,3,4,5) (3,4,5,6)  ect.. then the user gains 10 points.

I am unsure how to even approach the problem,
I select between 3-6 dice then click roll button and stores values in the array then I want to return true if the player hits a straight. I have tried various for loops and i keep getting incorrect values. An example i tried below:

```
function isStraight(array){
array.sort(); //sort array from lowest to highest 
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   if (array[i]<array[i-1]){
     return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
  }
```

for 6 dice I had the idea of summing all the numbers in the array and if it equals 21 then it would be true 1+2+3+4+5+6=21 but this wont work for dices lower than 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would order the array and then calculate if each number is 1 greater than the previous

```
var x = [3,2,6,7,1,9]



 x.sort(function(x,z) {return x-z})
    
    for (let i =1; i < x.length; i++)
    {
var previous = x[i-1];
var current = x[i]
      if (previous+1 !== current)
{
return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an equation that involves the number of dice, or use match statements.